# Return in React the same component but different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im learning ReactJS i have a question how to do render the same component but with different values.

```js
...
import ExampleComponent from "example"

Function Home(){
  
return(
   <div>
     <ExampleComponent name={"Data1"}  opcion={"other data"}/>
     <ExampleComponent name={"Data2"}  opcion={"other data"}/>
     <ExampleComponent name={"Data3"}  opcion={"other data"}/>
   </div>
)
}
```

So, i try with this, for more explicit in my case i use hooks and I've used an array.

```js
 const arrayData = [];
 
useEffect(() => {
    firebase.bd.ref("Example").on("value", function (snapshot) {
      //Get a Data in
      const elements = snapshot.child("name").val();
      for (const e in elements) {
        const data = snapshot
          .child("Example + "/" + e + "/opcion")
          .val();

        arrayData.push(e, data);
      }
    });
  });

/** Output: ["ExampleData","Opcion1","ExampleData", "Opcion2" ... ]  */


const Renderproyect = () => {
      for (let index = 0; index < arrayData.length; +2) {
      return (
        <div>
          <ExampleComponent name={index} description={index.description} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

function Home(){
  return(
   <div> 
     {Renderproyect()} 
   </div>
 )
}
```

How to do for works? I don't undersantd why dont return different components

Comment: Your fetching data async, so your first render will have nothing.  You normally use State to update the component when the data has been received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([])
useEffect(() => {
  firebase.bd.ref("Example").on("value", function (snapshot) {
    //Get a Data in
    const elements = snapshot.child("name").val();
    let temp = [];
    for (const e in elements) {
      const data = snapshot
        .child("Example" + "/" + e + "/opcion")
        .val();
      temp.push(e, data);
    }
    setData([...data, ...temp]);
  });
}, []);

const Renderproyect = () => {
  let aux = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < arrayData.length; +2) {
    aux.push(
      <div>
        <ExampleComponent name={index} description={index.description} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return aux;
};
```

You should also remove function Home(){} since you are working with a react component, your function should return a react component

so it would be something like

```
//state
// use effect
// Renderproyect
  return(
   <div> 
     <Renderproyect />
   </div>
 )
```

Comment: Yes, read your solution i understand your idea and works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a return in the loop, you will have only one ExampleComponent component.
Try to use

```
const Renderproyect = () => {
      return arrayData.map(a => {
       return (
        <div>
          <ExampleComponent name={index} description={index.description} />
        </div>
       );
      }
    }
  };
```